# auto click Javascript flash/swf button

Tags: javascript, flash

Is there a way to automatically click or activate a javascript flash button that is embeded in an html document?
I have tried

```
$(function(){
setTimeout(
    function(){
        $("#pipo").trigger("click");
        //optional
        $("#pipo").click();
    }
,5000);
```

});

also tried others i can find but none worked except if it is just an ordinary submit button.

A solution for this will be much appreciated,

Thx

Comment: What is a javascript flash button? Is it like an analogue digital watch?

Comment: Are you using any auto-click software? Add the relevant details. Otherwise no it can't be done. You have to program the swf button (using AS3 code) to respond to your specific Javascript code, in the first place before compiling the swf file.